# Skobler Android: How can I get all points to simulated route?

Tags: android, skmaps

I need to get many points of simulated route. My goal is get all points to paint a route using shape with SKPolyline in another view. How can I get that?

Regards.

Comment: We’ve asked the support of our development team

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your goal you want to draw the route that skobbler calculate for you using SKPolyline.

After request route calculation the callback onRouteCalculationCompleted will call with SKRouteInfo.

To get the route positions try:

```
        List<SKExtendedRoutePosition> list = SKRouteManager.getInstance().getExtendedRoutePointsForRoute(skRouteInfo.getRouteID());
```

Don't forget to set ExtendedPointsReturned=true when you request route calculation.

```
SKRouteSettings routeS = new SKRouteSettings();
    routeS.setStartCoordinate(startPosition.getCoordinate());
    routeS.setDestinationCoordinate(destinationPosition.getCoordinate());
    // number of alternative routes specified here
    routeS.setNoOfRoutes(1);
    routeS.setRouteMode(SKRouteSettings.SKRouteMode.CAR_FASTEST);
    //set true if you want the route is draw on map
    routeS.setRouteExposed();
    routeS.setExtendedPointsReturned(true);
    SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRoute(routeS);
```

Comment: Extended route does not provide the skpositions of the created route. do you have an idea why is it so?

Comment: Pls look at my answer below

Answer (score 1):

etzuk's answer is correct, but remember to cached the route before you can get all the skPosition of created route.
On onRouteCalculationCompleted, add saveRouteToCahce before getting route's coordinates like this:

```
SKRouteManager.getInstance().saveRouteToCache(skRouteInfo.getRouteID());
List<SKExtendedRoutePosition> coordinatesForRoute = SKRouteManager.getInstance()
                    .getExtendedRoutePointsForRoute(
                            skRouteInfo.getRouteID());
```